# "Free" licenses understanding and workaround for a simple java app

Tags: lgpl, java, epl

I'm developing a java app with my hands and feet. I intend to share it with people and it may become commercial.

He who knows can write it all down in notepad but I have been using Eclipse.

The first thing Eclipse did without me understanding what it did exactly was when I updated the "build path" to add a non standard java library.

This library is from LGPL licenses domain. The Eclipse license EPL and LGPL exclude each other.

What does this mean exactly and how can I get around the EPL license?

I understand you can add a new library to a project as a new dependency within a framework such as Maven or Spring but i'm not yet familiar with how and why to do this.

Comment: When you say "*I have been using Eclipse*", do you mean that you have been using Eclipse's [Java IDE](https://eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-developers/neon2) to develop your code?

Comment: Yes. Eclipse IDE for Java EE developers

Comment: Why do you think you are bound by the EPL?

Comment: https://github.com/Fazecast/jSerialComm/issues/53

Comment: I can see why you're bound by the LGPL, as your app is linked to a library that's available under that licence.  What I don't get, and what I'll ask again, is why you think you're bound by the EPL.  If you were *contributing* to Eclipse, you'd need to contribute code that could be bound by the EPL (which would preclude this LGPL-linked code), but you haven't said you're doing that.  You're not bound by the EPL just because you use an EPLed IDE to edit your code, any more than code compiled by gcc is automatically GPLed.  Have I missed something?

Comment: I'm not sure if editing the code is all I'm doing in Eclipse. I don't see what adding a library to build path does.

Comment: Even if you have included the library, that only explains why you're bound by the LGPL.  **Why do you think the EPL has any bearing on your code at all?**

Comment: Nicka, are you using any EPL-licensed files? Are you just worried that Eclipse injects some EPL-licensed artifacts into your code?

Comment: We could also use some more information about your use of the LGPL code. It's not just sitting there in the build path, you're presumably doing *something* with it. Are you calling some API? Are you using command-line interactions? Are you using C-style static or dynamic linking? Details here are important.

Comment: "Are you just worried that Eclipse injects some EPL-licensed artifacts into your code?" THIS. Updating path is doing something I don't see in the code. I will use some APIs and linking will be all static I think...